# Asset pipeline / precompile assets task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

How I can make the rake task

```
assets:precompile
```

available into my rails 2.3.14 app ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the source code of the assets:precompile rake task, you can find it here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake

Don't expect it to run as-is when you copy it to your lib/tasks in your rails 2.3.14 app with the sprockets and sprockets-helpers gems.

[update]

I made a simple precompiler rake task for use in rails 2.3.14 (without any javascript compression). You might want to change some things, depending on your configuration. Test the clean up task carefully, because it use a rm_rf command ;-)

```
BUILD_DIR = Rails.root.join("public/assets")
DIGEST = true

namespace :assets do

  task :compile => :cleanup do

    sprockets = Sprockets::Environment.new
    sprockets.append_path 'app/assets/images'
    sprockets.append_path 'app/assets/javascripts'
    sprockets.append_path 'app/assets/stylesheets'

    sprockets.each_logical_path do |logical_path|
      if asset = sprockets.find_asset(logical_path)
        target_filename =  DIGEST ? asset.digest_path : asset.logical_path
        prefix, basename = asset.pathname.to_s.split('/')[-2..-1]
        FileUtils.mkpath BUILD_DIR.join(prefix)
        filename = BUILD_DIR.join(target_filename)
        puts "write asset: #{filename}"
        asset.write_to(filename)
        #asset.write_to("#{filename}.gz") if filename.to_s =~ /\.(css|js)$/
      end
    end
  end

  # Cleanup asset directory
  task :cleanup do
    dirs = Dir.glob(File.join(BUILD_DIR.join("{*}")))
    dirs.each do |dir|
      puts "removing: #{dir}"
      FileUtils.rm_rf dir
    end
  end

end
```

[update #2]

I am now using this approach, and that works fine:
http://jaredonline.github.io/blog/2012/05/16/sprockets-2-with-rails-2-dot-3/

Comment: do you have any updates to this rake task? I notice you left out the final `end` so I was wondering if this was just a small piece of a larger .rake file.  Also, do you have any pointers on how to handle the js/css compression and minification?

Comment: The final end is still there, you have to scroll down, it doesn't fit the window. However I am now using this approach, and that works fine: http://jaredonline.github.io/blog/2012/05/16/sprockets-2-with-rails-2-dot-3/

Comment: Thanks Joris -- I actually found that solution yesterday and it SEEMS great.  However, when I try to run the `rake assets:precompile` task, it tries to compile ALL files in ALL paths I added in `sprockets.rb`.  Any ideas? See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730155/sprockets-asset-pipeline-in-rails-2-3

Comment: The assets in my project are simple, so I do not have that issue, but I gave you some pointers in  your other stackoverflow question. I hope it helps a bit in finding a solution.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a straightforward approach. The asset pipeline relies on several pieces of architecture in Rails 3.1.x that aren't present in Rails 2.3.

You can try using the approach that **[Davis Frank outlines here](http://pivotallabs.com/users/dwfrank/blog/articles/1972-giving-rails-2-the-asset-pipeline-)**, but be warned that it requires a number of steps.

Comment: I followed exactly this article, but there is not explained how to get this task to work...

Comment: That's not true; he explains it quite specifically in step 7: "Rails 3.1 provides the assets:precompile to be used as part of the deploy process Generate an empty Rails 3.1 app and copy it into lib/tasks. Copy the Sprockets configuration from your config.ru into this task."

Comment: If you have questions about the article, the best place to ask would be the author himself: http://pivotallabs.com/users/dwfrank/profile

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to explain it any better than he did, besides "Generate an empty Rails 3.1 app and copy it into lib/tasks." Move the app into `lib/tasks`. Which part are you stuck on?