# Sprockets/Asset Pipeline in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've followed the very thorough instructions below to add sprockets/asset pipeline to a legacy Rails 2.3.18 application I'm working on:

http://jaredonline.github.io/blog/2012/05/16/sprockets-2-with-rails-2-dot-3/

I have one outstanding issue -- in my `vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap` dir, I have copied all of the .scss files from the sass-bootstrap gem.

When I run the rake task provided in the above URL, `rake assets:precompile`, it errors out with this error: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/378

The issue is that sprockets is trying to compile some partial .scss files, which should just be compiled into the main application.css file.

Since I don't have the ability to change the `config.assets.precompile` Rails configuration in 2.3.18, how do you recommend I tell sprockets to ignore compiling these partial .scss files individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@joris provided good insight, but I had already figured it out by the time you replied!

Inside `assets.rake#internal_precompile`, change the last line to:

`manifest.compile [ Proc.new { |path| !%w(.js .css).include?(File.extname(path)) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]`

Found this answer a little ways down on this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: That's what I thought looking at the Sprockets 2 code. Great it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in Sprockets 2, I see manifest.compile accepts an argument. Browsing the code it looks like the argument is a kind of filter you can use on your assets. I didn't try or test anything with it, but maybe it gives you a starting point.