# Grunt or Gulp pipeline for Ruby application and sass

Tags: ruby, sass, gulp, gruntjs, google-amp

I am taking on an existing ruby project it doesn't currently have any sort of asses pipeline (all styles are just hardcoded).

I was hoping to use something like grunt of gulp. What I need to do is be able to compile sass from separate  .scss files and then add them to a `<style>` tag in the main moustache template.

Do you know of anyway to do this? The styles have be on the page in a `<style>` tag as its for Google AMP pages.

Comment: Bit confused! Its a rails project .. right ? which rails version is that ?

Comment: eughhhh all the info I have really is that it is ruby version 1.7.17

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730155/sprockets-asset-pipeline-in-rails-2-3